# Do i need to run the set production mode command every time i updated my magento2 code?

Tags: magento, magento2

I have already set my magento2 to production mode before. I would like to know if I should run `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production` every time if I added new code to my magento2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the intended workflow.  The way the system's designed you should

1. Work on your system in developer mode
2. When you're done, run `setup:di:compile` an `deploy:mode:set`
3. Push your system to production

Two and three may happen in different orders or be interlaced depending on the choices your team makes.

The main point is you're not meant to work on a system that's in production mode.  This does make some traditional PHP workflows impossible (i.e. where you're editing and working on the system as it's in production mode)